# Locked out of full disk encryption

Tags: boot, encryption, ecryptfs

I setup full disk encryption during my ubuntu install (14.04) and I recently rebooted and now I am locked out. I have not forgotten the password, I use it regularly. After boot when I put in the password I get this:

```
No key available for this passphrase.
cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?
```

I installed quite a few updates since I last rebooted and I also removed ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0 using apt-get remove as part of a walk through on removing home folder encryption.

Comment: ecryptfs-utils don't have to be removed just to switch to a non-encrypted home... what else did the walk-through do?

Comment: I did think that was a little weird. Here is the [walk through](http://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/). Does ecryptfs-utils or libecryptfs0 install something on the boot/grub partition?

Comment: I used apt-file to see what files are installed by ecryptfs-utils, libecrptfs0 and their dependencies, but nothing in /boot/ or /etc/grub.d/

Is it worth trying to reinstall those packages?

Comment: This has just happened to me on both my personal Ubuntu laptop and work desktop 2 days later!. Something has happened in the recent upgrade #

Comment: In that case I would imagine that this is about to happen to a lot of people. We probably aren't going to get very far on this stack overflow and should probably open a bug report. For me it was a system that I had just setup so it wasn't too much trouble to reinstall. If you open a bug report you should link us to it.